# When using refreshcontrol in tableview, how to know if the user is still holding down the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

Usually we do our job and call endrefreshing(). This causes the refresh to stop even if the user is still holding down the refresh. I don't want to interrupt the user action of refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` and `touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` methods to know when user star touching the view and when user has ended touching the view.